Is it possible to conditionally include a file in a quarto document?
This doc shows how to include a file:
{{< include _content.qmd >}}

And this doc shows how to conditionally include based on a metadata file:
::: {.content-hidden unless-meta="path.to.metadata"}

This content will be hidden unless there exists a metadata entry like such:

```yml
path:
  to:
    metadata: true
```

:::

However, I want to include a section if a data frame has some rows in it, i.e. an R boolean expression.
Is that possible?

How about this:
---
format: html
---

## first section

```{r}
nrow(mtcars)
```


```{r}
#| results: asis
#| echo: false
if(nrow(mtcars) > 10) {
  paste(
    "",
  "{{< include _example_include.qmd >}}",
  "") |> cat(sep = "\n")
}
```

with _example_include.qmd:
## section cond

Load the `sp500` from [`great_tables`](https://posit-dev.github.io/great-tables/).

Result:


This works for me, thanks!
